# Samsung monitor "check signal cable"

Tags: multiple-monitors, vga, dvi

yesterday I built a new PC and got it all to work. On my old desktop I used to have dual monitors. (1 connected with DVI, 1 connected with VGA).
Now with my new GPU (GTX 1070) it only has a DVI connection. So I went out today to get myself a DVI-VGA adapter. The plan is to connect one monitor with HDMI and one with the DVI-VGA adapter. The problem is when I try to connect the second monitor (the one with the adapter), it just says "Check Signal Cable". The monitor is a Samsung Syncmaster 2243SN. Everything fits perfectly though. Does anyone know a solution to this?

Here are some pictures of the setup and the adapter:

[image: VGA-DVI adapter]
[image: Setup/Error]

Comment: What did you buy? A DVI to VGA passive plug or an expensive active convertor from digital DVI to analog VGA?  (DVI to VGA plugs only work if the card actually outputs a VGA signal on specif DVI plug. Those were used during the introduction of DVI to easy migration. Not sure if any modern card still does that, so you would need relative expensive active convertors).

Comment: Additionally, `VGA, even in its highest resolution from SVGA, is only capable of an 800 x 600-pixel resolution`. - So maybe the monitor doesn't support such a lower resolution?

Comment: I bought this one: https://www.bol.com/nl/p/brauch-dvi-24-1-male-naar-vga-female-adapter/9200000050465652/ so I'm guessing it's not the right adapter then..? As for the resolution, it does support such a low resolution. It's meant as my second monitor anyway, my primary one is a 144hz 1920x1080 one. So I don't mind the resoltuion on my second monitor anyway as it's pretty much just for simple things as facebook and looking something up while gaming etc

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you bought a passive DVI-D (24+1) adapter, which won't work with VGA since it doesn't support the analog signal. You'd either have to buy a DVI-I (24+5) adapter if your graphics card actually has a DVI-I connection or an expensive DVI-D digital-to-analog converter.

Answer (score 0):

You need to buy Active DVI-D to VGA adapter - https://amzn.to/38TcKQq
Those passive adapters do not work. FAKE.